# Tweet to a user timeline with nodejs

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I have a nodeJS app where user can login with their twitter account via passportJS. It works fine.

I would like my app to tweet to the connected user timeline (as it was him who tweet). Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

EDIT: more infos

I have tried the [twitt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) package

```
var Twitter = require('twit');
var config= {
    username: 'a-username',
    consumer_key: 'xxx',
    consumer_secret: 'xxx',
    access_token: 'xxx',
    access_token_secret: 'xxx'
};
var T = new Twitter(config);
T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'a message' }, function(err, data, response)     {
    if(err) {
        return reject(err);
    }
    return data.id_str; // the tweet id
}
```

*I can tweet with my app but not with another account*

*Sorry if the question looks stupid, I'm new here, hope won't be too ridiculous*

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my post with small piece of my code

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the [oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth) package. Refer to twitter documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request).

Comment: Did you get your solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing, twitter's documentation has a clear example of how to do that